# Como pegar o numero de usuarios com menor tempo em cada clan?

Tags: sqlite

Tenho 2 tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE `deathrun_records` (
    `sid64` STRING,
    `mapname`   STRING,
    `seconds`   REAL
);

CREATE TABLE `clan_members` (
    `sid64` STRING,
    `nome_clan` STRING,
    `prop`  STRING
);
```

A primeira tabela guarda o tempo dos usuarios em cada mapa, e a segunda guarda o clan dos usuarios.

Preciso de um `SELECT` que retorne os clans com usuarios que mais possuem recordes(menor tempo em um mapa).

O que eu fiz até agora:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordes FROM deathrun_records d JOIN clan_members c ON c.sid64 = d.sid64 GROUP BY c.nome_clan ORDER BY recordes
```

O meu problema é para criar um `WHERE CLAUSE` para pegar somente o jogador com menor tempo em cada mapa. Como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa fazer uma consulta agrupando o menor tempo por clan, e depois uma consulta por fora para pegar quem é que tem o menor tempo desse clan, então a consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
    d2.*,
    c2.*
FROM deathrun_records d2
INNER JOIN clan_members c2
ON c2.sid64 = d2.sid64
INNER JOIN(
SELECT 
    d.mapname,
    d.sid64,
    d.seconds,
    c.nome_clan,
    MIN(d.seconds) seconds_join
FROM deathrun_records d 
JOIN clan_members c 
ON c.sid64 = d.sid64 
GROUP BY c.nome_clan
ORDER BY nome_clan, seconds DESC) as aux
ON (aux.nome_clan = c2.nome_clan 
    AND seconds_join = d2.seconds 
)
```

Sendo assim você pode contar o resultado da `query` agrupando por `d2.seconds` e `c2.nome_clan` ai você terá quantos players por clan possuem o menor tempo, dessa maneira estamos retornando os usuários com menor tempo por tempo do clan, se quiser ver por tempo global só retirar do `GROUP BY` da primeira consulta o campo `nome_clan`.

Na query que eu fiz acima você terá os players com menor tempo do CLAN nessa que fiz agora você qtd players por clan tem o menor tempo GLOBAL, segue:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS qtd_player,
    c2.nome_clan
FROM deathrun_records d2
INNER JOIN clan_members c2
ON c2.sid64 = d2.sid64
INNER JOIN(
SELECT 
    d.mapname,
    d.sid64,
    d.seconds,
    c.nome_clan,
    MIN(d.seconds) seconds_join
FROM deathrun_records d 
JOIN clan_members c 
ON c.sid64 = d.sid64 
ORDER BY nome_clan, seconds DESC) as aux
ON seconds_join = d2.seconds 
GROUP BY nome_clan
```

Comment: "você terá quantos players por clan possuem o menor tempo", exatamente isso que eu quero. Tentei fazer do jeito que você falou aqui e não consegui...

Comment: @Francisco você quer pegar o menor tempo global? e depois ver por clan? ai eu edito a query e envio aqui